# .htaccess: URL Rewriting Pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^newest/?$ index.php?type=newest
```

This does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^newest/(\d+)*/?$ ./index.php?type=newest&p=$1
```

The rest of my re-write:

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This works on my localhost running xampp, but it not working on my web host. What could be the problem before I contact them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A couple of things to check ...**

You might need to enable htaccess in your apache config file (httpd.conf) by uncommenting the following:

```
;LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

---

Try ensuring that the directory entry in httpd.conf for your server doesn't contain

```
AllowOverride None
```

as this will prevent the .htaccess file from being used in the individual directory. It should look something like this (note the **AllowOverride All**):

```
<Directory /var/www/www.mysite.com>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

---

Also in httpd.conf, make sure that .htaccess is actually the name apache expects for access files. The `AccessFileName` directive can specify this value. For example:

```
<virtualhost>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DirectoryRoot /var/www/www.mysite.com
    AccessFileName .customhtaccess
</virtualhost>
```

If the `AccessFileName` directive is set to something different, an .htaccess file won't be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

What is your intent with this rule

> RewriteRule ^newest/(\d+)*/?$ ./index.php?type=newest&p=$1

If it is to match 0 or more digits it should be

> RewriteRule ^newest/(\d)*/?$ index.php?type=newest&p=$1 [NC,L]

If it is to match 1 or more digits it should be

> RewriteRule ^newest/(\d)+/?$ index.php?type=newest&p=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a more efficient way to do this. I recommend to use this pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

To redirect all of requests to your index file then you're able to parse URL and do what yo need. This is not the correction for your question but it would be an alternative way to avoid your kind of working.